# Python logging module on Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, logging

Where should I see the logging output on Eclipse while debugging ? and when running ?

Answer (score 2):

It will depends on how you configure your logging system. If you use only print statement, it should be shown in the `console` view of eclipse.

If you use `logging` and you configured a Console handler it should also be displayed in the `console` eclipse view.
If you configured only file handler in the logging configuration, you'll have to tail the log files ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here an example that worked for me:

```
# LOG
log = logging.getLogger("appname")
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fmt = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(fmt)
log.addHandler(ch)
log.debug("something happened") # Will print on console '2013-01-26 12:58:28,974 - appname - DEBUG - something happened'
```